# App working with spring boot starter 2.0.4 but not working with 2.1.6 release

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

We just trying to migrate our app from Spring boot 2.0.4 to 2.1.6 and some of the functionalities on our app are not working especially where we have used jpa repository's saveandflush method it started throwing constraint violation exception on the table that it is trying to saveandflush, can someone help me what got changed in these two versions ?

Comment: have you checked the release notes between those versions. Namely 2.0.x and 2.1.x. The path versions rarely introduce breaking changes unless they are regressions. 

Additionally adding your entities and configurations might help

Comment: Codebase would be nice to see or are we going to guess?